# moving to a particular column in an empty line

Tags: vim

I'm trying to use VIM for Word Processing situations where, for example, I might need to put the date at the 70th column of a line that has no other text on it. So, for example, if there's currently no text on line 1 and I want to insert something at column 70, the only way I know how to get to column 70 is by hitting the space bar while in insert mode, a very slow process.

Is there a way to do what I'm trying to achieve in VIM?  i.e. to jump ahead to a particular column in a blank line. Even if I could do something like `70l` (move 70 spaces to the right) would be amazing, but it doesn't work on a line without any text.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You could also consider virtualedit which allows you to pace the cursor any where regardless of if there is a character there.

Use (short form `set ve=all`)

```
:set virtualedit=all
```

to enable it. Then use `70|` to go to the 70 column.  Take a took at `:help 'virtual edit'`

To turn it off use `:set virtualedit=` (Short form `set ve=`)

Comment: thanks, it's great but how to unset, doesn't say in docs, `set novirtualedit` doesn't do it, nor does `set novirtualedit=all`

Comment: This is a great answer, I did not know about the `virtualedit` option! @BrainLikeADullPencil: the default is `set virtualedit=`, with no arguments. (edit - oh, he mentions that in the answer too, I suppose it was edited to contain this information)

Answer (score 3):

You can do `70i` followed by `esc` (that's <kbd>7</kbd><kbd>0</kbd><kbd>i</kbd><kbd>spacebar</kbd><kbd>Esc</kbd>).

For the specific case you mention - adding the date on the 70th column:

- <kbd>6</kbd><kbd>9</kbd><kbd>i</kbd><kbd>spacebar</kbd><kbd>Esc</kbd><kbd>$</kbd>

  This will create 69 spaces and the cursor will be on the 69th column;
- `:r !date` <kbd>Enter</kbd>

  This will copy the output of the `date` command into the edit buffer (on the next line);
- <kbd>backspace</kbd><kbd>J</kbd>

After this step, you have the date, starting on the 70th column.

There probably is an easier way, but at least this one works for sure.

Comment: really nice thanks. I'll see what others come up with before I accept

Comment: What is `backspace J`actually telling VIM to do? I see that it works in this situation but would like to know the instruction it's giving

Comment: If you accept it, great! But even if this isn't the accepted answer, if you find it worthy, you can always upvote it ;)

Comment: `backspace` is just my way of moving to the previous line. You can also use the `k` character to do the same thing (but backspace moves it to the end of the previous line, which is intuitively what I wanted to do, even if it isn't actually necessary). `J` joins the current line with the next one, effectively making them a single, larger line. Since the `:r` command inserts the output in the next line, I had to join them.

Comment: your solution is best for vi, but the virtualedit response is better for vim (imo)

Comment: Inserting 70 spaces quickly is better than toggling a setting for a one-time use case.

Comment: @ADTC but why not leave virtualedit set permanently? Then no need to toggle. Is there a disadvantage that you can inform me of? Thanks

Comment: I mentioned "one-time use case". If you're using it all then sure, leave it turned on. All I'm saying is using a command to insert 70 spaces is quicker if you're just doing it once in a blue moon.

Comment: @ADTC I understand, i just wondered if you knew of a reason why I'd want to turn off virtual edit...still a newbie learning

Answer (score 1):

Not the prettiest way to do it, but you can modify the `shiftwidth`, which is the size of a single tab. In command mode type in `:set shiftwidth=1` and then type in what you want at column 70, then use the command: <kbd>V</kbd> (uppercase ´v´) to highlight your current line and then type <kbd>7</kbd><kbd>0</kbd><kbd>></kbd>. That should tab your text over 70 columns.

Then after that, it might be a good idea to set your `shiftwidth` back to 4, to make tabbing more consistent. Unless this is a task you do pretty often and you have no use for tabbing.

Comment: hmm, I have a WordPressing function that I can toggle (see http://www.drbunsen.org/writing-in-vim/) I guess I could put the shift width in there and then it will revert back when I leave WP mode

Comment: This is a good idea, but only if you have the `:set expandtab` activated, so that you actually write 70 spaces, instead of a single tab character.

Answer (score 0):

Another way can be to set `tabstop` to 70 and set `expandtab` to expand tabs to spaces:

```
:se ts=70
:se et
```

And then you can hit the tab key to get to the 70th column.